# NHibernate.QueryException ActiveRecord

Tags: c#, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

```
   [ActiveRecord]   
    public class Category
   {
    private int _id;
    private string _name;
    private Category _category;

    [PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.HiLo, "id", Params = "max_lo=9")]
    public long Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        protected internal set { _id = value; }
    }
    [Property]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
    [BelongsTo("ParentCategoryId")]
    public Category ParentCategory
    {
        get { return _category;}
        set { _category = value; }
    }       
}
```

Table is correctly generated in the database and data can be insterted without any problems

But when I'm running

```
        var criteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Category>
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ParentCategory.ParentCategoryId", testCategory.id));           
        Assert.That(m_repository.FindAll(criteria).Length, Is.EqualTo(1));
```

I'm reciving QueryException

> `NHibernate.QueryException : could not
>   resolve property:
>   ParentCategory.ParentCategoryId'

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching the ParentCategory property of a Category, which is itself a Category. Your DetachedCriteria should be:

```
   var criteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Category>()
                                  .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ParentCategory.Id",
                                                       testCategory.id));
```